# Passing access_token to access private Spotify playlists

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I am working with the web-api-auth-examples repository from [this link](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples)

All in all a good example and made me understand the authentication code flow better. Now I am trying to move into something more difficult such as getting the logged in user's playlists with the scope: 'playlist-read-private'.

So the code is the one from authorization_code/app.js, [see here](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/authorization_code/app.js)

After(so outside) the declaration of app.get(/callback) callback I'm trying something like this:

```
app.get('/playlists', function(req, res, body) {
    var scope = 'playlist-read-private';
    var access_token = body.access_token;
    console.log(access_token);
});
```

Logging access_token I get undefined in the terminal, even if I don't define it as part of body it's undefined.

The question: How do I get the access token that is passed on the url bar and request user data with it?!

Comment: The auth flow should be: 1. request login, 2. use the returned code to get an access and refresh token, 3. use the access token to make calls, 4. when it expires use the refresh token to get a new access token. 
You store the access and refresh token in your system (e.g. the database) 
You set the scope during the initial login flow. The scope is linked to the access/refresh token so dictates what you can call via the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the same [Github tutorial that you linked](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/authorization_code), inside of the `public/index.html` file you can see how they are passing data to the routes by looking at the `refresh_token` example request. To pass the `access_token` to your `/playlists` route, you will need an `ajax` request.

The request would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/playlist',
  data: {
    'access_token': access_token 
  }
})
...
```

And then inside your `app.get('/playlists')` you will be able to reference in from `req.query`.

```
app.get('/playlist', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query); // will return { access_token: XYZ }
});;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, it works as you described! But can I get the key alone like: access_token and pass it to a variable in the app.js?! Doing req.query is giving me not only the access token but also other information about the logged in profile.